# A Jordan curve cannot be everywhere dense in $[0,1]^2$

Tags: general-topology, curves

How to prove that a Jordan curve cannot be everywhere dense in $[0,1]^2$ ?

Comment: A Jordan curve's image is compact. Therefore the image would be the whole square. It is also a homeomorphism to $S^1$. Now, remove two points from $S^1$ and the corresponding points from the square, and compare connectedness of the results.

Comment: @Hellen Thanks! I forgot to use compacity. Additional note: removing only one interior point would be sufficient to use the connectedness argument you mention.

Comment: Removing one point both remain connected. Maybe you would like to argue that one is contractible and the other is not. then you don't need to remoe any points!? According to the taste.

Comment: @Hellen If you remove an **interior** point of a segment then it is disconnected while the square minus a point remains connected.

Comment: I understand now that you are thinking of the domain of the curve as an interval. My domain was a circle $S^1$ such that I can say that the curve is a homeomorphism.

Comment: By applying the previous comments you can see that a Jordan curve is closed and nowhere-dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Hellen’s comment for answer.

A Jordan curve's image is compact. Therefore the image would be the whole square. It is also a homeomorphism to $S^1$. Now, remove two points from $S^1$ and the corresponding points from the square, and compare connectedness of the results.